# Но твой котяра — нехорош / не хорош

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

Как правильно?

> Но твой котяра — нехорош / не хорош.
> Куст этот неколюч / не колюч.
> Я ненищ / не нищ.
> Он недобр / не добр.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

***Но твой котяра — нехорош** (= плох), облезлый какой-то.* Утверждение.

***Но твой котяра — не хорош**, хотя в общем-то и не плох.* Отрицание.

**Вариант 2**

***Куст этот неколюч** (= без шипов), так что перелезай через него смело.* Утверждение.

*Колючий куст? Нет, **куст этот не колюч**.* Отрицание.

**Вариант 3**

*Ладно уж, сам заплачу, **я не нищ**. В том числе умом и талантом, имей в виду.* Только отрицание, нет прилагательного "ненищий".

**Вариант 4**

***Он недобр** (= зол) с самого утра, контрольную точно не отменит.* Утверждение.

***Он не добр,** хотя жалостлив и сентиментален.* Отрицание.

Comment: Ставлю плюс. А почему нет прилагательного _ненищий_?

Comment: В словаре не нашла, в текстах тоже. Нет утвердительного значения. Не нищий, а какой?